# Python/Django django-registration add an extra field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

I have read a lot about how to add an extra field when using Django-registration, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565814/django-user-userprofile-and-admin), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109/extending-the-user-model-with-custom-fields-in-django/965883#965883) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565814/django-user-userprofile-and-admin). The code snippets are:
forms.py (from the registration app)

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$', max_length=30, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict), label=_("Username"), error_messages={ 'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters, numbers and underscores.") })
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=75)), label=_("Email"))
    password1=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False), label=_("Password"))
    institute=forms.CharField(max_length=50) #This is the new!
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict, render_value=False), label=_("Password (again)"))
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

I use the django's registration  save method, which is in the default backend:

```
def register(self, request, **kwargs):
    username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site)

    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

In models.py I have created a new class:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):  
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    institute=models.CharField(max_length=50)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):  
    if created:  
        profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

In the admin.py:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = UserProfile
class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

I have not altered anything alse. When I render the form I can see the Institute Field I have added. When I am in the admin site I can see the user profile of each user. However nothing is saved there when I create a new user while the other details of the user are normally saved. I think that I need some kind of configuration but where? Maybe in the files of the Django-registration app?

Comment: The `RegistrationForm` which you have posted is incomplete, where is save method?

Comment: I use the django administration's backend method, I have included it in the original post. Probably somewhere here is thw problem..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have figured out a solution to this problem, and I will post it here in case somebody can use it. It's pretty simple, I suppose.

**Step 1** Add a new model, which will be a profile, in the models.py:

```
#models.py
class user_profile(models.Model):
     user=models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
     institution=models.CharField(max_length=200)

     def __unicode__(self):
         return u'%s %s' % (self.user, self.institution)
```

**Step 2** Create the form that will use this model:

```
#forms.py
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
from Test.models import user_profile

class UserRegForm(RegistrationForm):
    institution=forms.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**Step 3** Create ragbackend.py and define how the data will be saved:

```
from Test.models import user_profile
from forms import *

def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    form = UserRegForm(request.POST)
    data = user_profile(user=user)
    data.institution = form.data["institution"]
    data.save()

from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

**Step 4** Go to urls.py and make the following changes:

```
import regbackend 
from registration.views import register

url(r'^accounts/register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend','form_class': UserRegForm}, name='registration_register'),
(r'^accounts/', include('registration.urls')),
```

Note that you have to put the URLs in that order. Easy to understand why.

**Step 5** Now everything works, but you cannot see the information in the admin site. So you have to go to admin.py and add:

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Test.models import user_profile
admin.site.unregister(User)
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = user_profile

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline, ]
admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

And that's it. Do not forget the `syncdb` before `runserver`. I hope this will help someone.

Comment: Really struggling with this (have tried other methods too so am getting desperate!). Your solution gives me a database transaction error, as detailed in question below. Can you help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695713/django-reg-extend-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-o

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Garrett's answer, I was getting a "cannot import name register" error with django-registration version 0.8. I believe this is because of class-based views, so update `urls.py` accordingly:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from registration.backends.default.views import RegistrationView
from abby.apps.accounts.forms import UserRegForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=UserRegForm)),
)
```