# Django-registration: How to make account creation ask for first/last name

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm using the Django-Registration package to have users create accounts, authenticate them and log in to my webapp.

However, the form/view for account creation doesn't ask the user for a firstname/last name (those fields are part of the model BTW). It only asks for their email address, login ID and password (twice). I would like it to ask for the user's first name/last name (these fields can be optional... but it should still ask). I cannot find the form and view files to modify such that it asks for this info. I have modified the template file. But without the form and view modifications that's useless. How is this done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your forms.py, extend the DjangoRegistration form like:

```
class MyExtendedForm(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(label="first_name"))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(label="last_name"))
```

In the `urls.py`, tell django-registration to use this extended form:

```
# using my registration form to override the default
(r'^register/$', 
    register, 
    {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend',
     'form_class': MyExtendedForm}),
```

Define `user_created` to save the extra information:

```
def user_created(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Called via signals when user registers. Creates different profiles and
    associations
    """
    form = MyExtendedForm(request.Post)
    # Update first and last name for user
    user.first_name=form.data['first_name']
    user.last_name=form.data['last_name']
    user.save()
```

Then, register for signals from django-registration to call your function after any registration is processed:

```
from registration.signals import user_registered
user_registered.connect(user_created)
```

Comment: After making some relatively minor edits to your code above, this worked. Thanks!

Comment: My edits still haven't posted. And your code won't work without them. So for the benefit of others, I'm posting them here:

There is a missing closing parenthesis on each of the two lines in class MyExtendedForm. Also the first line in user_created should be form = MyExtendedForm(request.Post). And the definition of user_created must occur before you register it for the signal from Django-registration.

Comment: Yes, I had just given a prototype code in logical order. Glad it worked for you.

Comment: Ran into a "cannot import name register" error using django-registration 0.8. [I've posted a fix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16366997/720054).

Comment: There is a typo.It should be `request.POST` (all uppercase)

Answer (score 2):

Once you have everything set up like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61283399/3842788) use following CustomUserForm:

```
class CustomUserForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2']
```

Answer (score 0):

To add the fields `first_name` and `last_name` from the default Django `User` model [provide your own formclass](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.2/custom-user.html#writing-your-form-subclass):

Prepend the two fields to `Meta.fields` of the default `RegistrationForm`:

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class RegistrationWithNameForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        fields = ["first_name", "last_name"] + RegistrationForm.Meta.fields
```

Override the default `RegistrationView` by adding a path to `urls.py`:

```
from django_registration.backends.activation.views import RegistrationView
from yourapp.forms import RegistrationWithNameForm

path('accounts/register/',
  RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=RegistrationWithNameForm),
  name='django_registration_register',
),
path("accounts/", include("django_registration.backends.activation.urls")),
```

Testcase:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse

class RegistrationTestCase(TestCase):
    registration_url = reverse("django_registration_register")
    test_username = "testuser"
    post_data = {
        "first_name": "TestFirstName",
        "last_name": "TestLastName",
        "username": test_username,
        "email": "testuser@example.com",
        "password1": "mypass",
        "password2": "mypass"
    }

    def test_register(self):
        response = self.client.post(self.registration_url, self.post_data)
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("django_registration_complete"))
        user = get_user_model().objects.get(username=self.test_username)
        # Assert all fields are present on the newly registered user
        for field in ["username", "first_name", "last_name", "email"]:
            self.assertEqual(self.post_data[field], getattr(user, field))
```