# How to redirect users to a specific url after registration in django registration?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-registration

So I am using django-registration app to implement a user registration page for my site. I used Django's backends.simple views which allows the users to immediately login after registration. My question is how do I redirect them to my other app's page located in the same directory as the project.

Here is what my main urls.py looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^upload/', include('mysite.fileupload.urls')),
    # Examples:
    # url(r'^$', 'mysite.views.home', name='home'),
    # url(r'^mysite/', include('mysite.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    # url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

import os
urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^media/(.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'media')}),
)
```

fileupload is the name of the other app I have in the project directory mysite.

This is what the backends.simple.urls looks like:

```
"""
URLconf for registration and activation, using django-registration's
one-step backend.

If the default behavior of these views is acceptable to you, simply
use a line like this in your root URLconf to set up the default URLs
for registration::

    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),

This will also automatically set up the views in
``django.contrib.auth`` at sensible default locations.

If you'd like to customize registration behavior, feel free to set up
your own URL patterns for these views instead.

"""


from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(r'^register/$',
                           RegistrationView.as_view(),
                           name='registration_register'),
                       url(r'^register/closed/$',
                           TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'),
                           name='registration_disallowed'),
                       (r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
                       )
```

And here is the backends.simple.views:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from registration import signals
from registration.views import RegistrationView as BaseRegistrationView


class RegistrationView(BaseRegistrationView):
    """
    A registration backend which implements the simplest possible
    workflow: a user supplies a username, email address and password
    (the bare minimum for a useful account), and is immediately signed
    up and logged in).

    """
    def register(self, request, **cleaned_data):
        username, email, password = cleaned_data['username'], cleaned_data['email'], cleaned_data['password1']
        User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

        new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, new_user)
        signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                     user=new_user,
                                     request=request)
        return new_user

    def registration_allowed(self, request):
        """
        Indicate whether account registration is currently permitted,
        based on the value of the setting ``REGISTRATION_OPEN``. This
        is determined as follows:

        * If ``REGISTRATION_OPEN`` is not specified in settings, or is
          set to ``True``, registration is permitted.

        * If ``REGISTRATION_OPEN`` is both specified and set to
          ``False``, registration is not permitted.

        """
        return getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_OPEN', True)

    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return (user.get_absolute_url(), (), {})
```

I tried the changing the get_success_url function to just return the url I want which is /upload/new but it still redirected me to users/**insert username** page and gave an error. How do I redirect the user to the upload/new page where the other app resides after registration?

Answer (score 18):

Don't change the code in the `registration` module. Instead, subclass the `RegistrationView`, and override the `get_success_url` method to return the url you want.

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return "/upload/new"
```

Then include your custom registration view in your main `urls.py`, instead of including the simple backend urls.

```
urlpatterns = [
    # your custom registration view
    url(r'^register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    # the rest of the views from the simple backend
    url(r'^register/closed/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/registration_closed.html'),
                          name='registration_disallowed'),
    url(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),
]
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put the class MyRegistrationView? Does it go on the views.py in the backend.simple folder or the one inside the registration folder?

Comment: As I said above, don't change the code in the registration module. It would make it much, much harder to upgrade to the next version of django-registration. You can put the class in one of your own app's views.py. You could include it in the `urls.py` if you prefer, since it's only three lines long.

Comment: So I tried this I put the both the blocks of code in the backends.simple.urls.py Since, the main urls.py file in my project folder makes a call to the simple.urls as you can see from above. It still doesn't work and redirects to the user/username page right after registration (not login)

Comment: I've said twice already not to edit the code in the registration module. Since you're still trying to edit the `backends.simple.urls.py`, I can't help you any more.

Comment: I get it that I shouldn't be modifying the code in registration module but, the changes I made in the backends.simple.urls.py should make it work right? Let me try it exactly your way and get back to you. Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

I am using django_registration 3.1 package. I have posted all 3 files (views.py urls.py forms.py) that are needed to use this package. 
To redirect user to a custom url on successfull registration, create a view that subclasses RegistrationView. Pass in a success_url of your choice.

**Views.py:**

```
from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('homepage:homepage')  # using reverse() will give error
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django_registration.backends.one_step.views import RegistrationView
from core.forms import CustomUserForm
from .views import MyRegistrationView

app_name = 'core'
urlpatterns = [

    # login using rest api
    path('api/', include('core.api.urls')),

    # register for our custom class
    path('auth/register/', MyRegistrationView.as_view(
        form_class=CustomUserForm
    ), name='django_registration_register'),

    path('auth/', include('django_registration.backends.one_step.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))

]
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django_registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from core.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserForm(RegistrationForm):
    class Meta(RegistrationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set [SIMPLE_BACKEND_REDIRECT_URL](https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simple-backend.html#configuration) in `settings.py`.

**settings.py**

```py
SIMPLE_BACKEND_REDIRECT_URL = '/upload/new'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish, you can modify the following file **/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/registration/backends/simple/urls.py**, changing the path, for example:

**Before modifying:**

```
success_url = getattr (settings, 'SIMPLE_BACKEND_REDIRECT_URL', '/'),
```

**After modifying:**

```
success_url = getattr (settings, 'SIMPLE_BACKEND_REDIRECT_URL', '/upload/new'),
```

Regards.

Diego