# Django registration: Redirect after registering fails because of missing argument

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-registration

I am currently going through the tango with django tutorial and trying to implement django registration with redirect after it was successful.

I followed both the tutorial and what I found in [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708787/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-specific-url-after-registration-in-django-registratio?rq=1)another question.

When I register, I get

```
TypeError at /accounts/register/
get_success_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView

class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        return '/student/'


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^student/', include('student.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Add in this url pattern to override the default pattern in accounts.
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', MyRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'', include('registration.auth_urls')),

]
```

Anyone an idea what I might be doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things have changed from then, now you supply 'user' as first positional argument. And there is no `request` argument for `get_success_url` method. Your code should look like this:

```
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, user):
        return '/student/'
```

See: Old [RegistrationView](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/1.0/registration/views.py#L48) and new [RegistrationView](https://github.com/ubernostrum/django-registration/blob/master/registration/views.py#L37) at github.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes it's so easy.