# Django registration Type error at /accounts/register/ get_success_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-registration

Using the Django registration redux plugin to create a form page after a user has successfully registered for my app. However I keep receiving this error `TypeError at /accounts/register/
get_success_url() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'` after completing the registration. It should redirect to a page with a form shown in the method below

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView


# my new reg view, subclassing RegistrationView from our plugin
class MyRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, request, user):
        # the named URL that we want to redirect to after
        # successful registration
        return ('registration_create_word')
```

Here is the url path
`path('accounts/create_word/', views.create_word, name='registration_create_word'),`

I have attempted changing the parameters to just `user` however i received the same error except it is missing `self`. 
Not sure what I am missing. I found a similar question ([How to redirect users to a specific url after registration in django registration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708787/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-specific-url-after-registration-in-django-registratio?noredirect=1&lq=1)) however i still am receiving errors

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can not just add an extra parameter `user`.

Comment: initialize user **self.request.user** this what you mean?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708787/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-specific-url-after-registration-in-django-registratio?rq=1 shows i can use `user` as parameter. When i remove `user` I get `ValueError at /accounts/create_word/
The view collection.views.create_word didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`