# django-registration additional field in signup form

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-registration

I am using django registration form and I want to add an extra field age to sign up form and i want to save that field to my model named profile.How can i do it.What will be my view?

**my models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

Comment: I think , its may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726725/python-django-django-registration-add-an-extra-field

Comment: @hizbul thanks for your answer.Do you know how to validate that custom field?

Comment: if you get any help from this , you may accept and up vote in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention you have a model class which is **my models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

I think in this case you may get help from this :
[Python/Django django-registration add an extra field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726725/python-django-django-registration-add-an-extra-field)

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    age = models.IntegerField()
```

for more detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model