# Cannot see extended User model field in admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have added a field to my User model called extra, as follows:-

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
extra = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

# when a user is created, make sure an ExtendedUser is created too
def create_extended_user(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        extended_user = ExtendedUser(user=instance)
        extended_user.save()
post_save.connect(create_extended_user, sender=User)
```

In my admin.py, I try to ensure that I can edit this extra field when I'm editing a user:-

```
class ExtendedUserInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ExtendedUser
    fk_name = 'user'
    max_num = 1

class ExtendedUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [ExtendedUserInline]

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, ExtendedUserAdmin)
```

However, I can't see the extra field in the admin page for User.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: nope, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Adding an extra comma doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted the development server since editing `admin.py`?

See also [this very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565814/django-user-userprofile-and-admin).

Comment: Yup, restarted the dev server - makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your first block of code looks ok to me, although you might want to use the decorators for readability. Here's an updated example.

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User)
extra = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)

# when a user is created, make sure an ExtendedUser is created too
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)    
def create_extended_user(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
        if created:
            extended_user = ExtendedUser(user=instance)
            extended_user.save()
```

Updated Answer:

You need to set AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'app_name.ExtendedUser'

[Here's a post](http://igorsobreira.com/2010/12/11/extending-user-model-in-django.html) that did pretty much the same as you.  Some of the comments below are worth reading.

Comment: Sadly, that doesn't work.

Surely the UserAdmin is the wrong class name here anyway? The one I used was ExtendedUserAdmin - as I was extending the usual UserAdmin.

Comment: You're right.  Answer deleted.  Going to try replicating with your code.

Comment: That doesn't seem to do it either. Still can't see the extra field in the admin interface.