# In Django, is there a way to show the admin for a model under a different app?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've extended the standard `User` with a `Profile` model using a one-to-one relationship:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, editable=False)
    # Additional user information fields
```

This is in an app called `account_custom`. The issue is that in the admin site, I would like this model to show up along with `User` under "Authentication and Authorization".

I was able to make this show up in the right place in the admin by setting `Meta.app_label`:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'auth'
        db_table = 'account_custom_profile'
```

I set `Meta.db_table` so this uses the existing database table, and everything seems to function properly.

**The problem** is that Django wants to generate migrations for this, one in `account_custom` to delete the table and one in `auth` to create it again. I'm guessing this would either fail or wipe out the data depending on the order the migrations are run, but the deeper problem is that it's trying to create a migration in `auth` which isn't part of my code base.

Is there a way around this, or is there some better way to control where a `ModelAdmin` shows up in the admin site?

Comment: If all you want is to have user profile in admin along with user the better option is too show user profile inline in user admin, checkout this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565814/django-user-userprofile-and-admin .. Simple is better than complex ;)

Comment: That is much cleaner and simpler, thanks!